# What is considered to be a "topic element"?

Tags: grammar, linguistics

I can't make out clearly what could be defined as a "topic element".
In "A Communicative Grammar of English", Geoffrey Leech has written:

- Fronting is often accompanied by inversion; that is, not only the topic element,
  but the verb phrase, or part of it, is moved before the subject.

Accompanied by this diagram:

[image: Example of Subject-Verb inversion]

Now, "x" in the above diagram is stated to be "the topic element". However, from what I've learned, the topic is usually either "given info" or used to link statements. Moreover, they are usually subjects. Yet here "down" and "never" are considered to be "the topic element"? I'm truly desperate for an answer here.

Comment: Author seems to be using *topic element* as the keyword of the sentence - the word that makes the most difference. Sometimes *not* is a keyword, sometimes *if*. "**If** I can find an extra $1,000 for you, I'll be sure to get that to you tout suite."

Comment: What's the full context? I suspect that "fronting" is supposed to refer to something different from what the diagram is illustrating.